# Spring integration - Is multiple instance of Jboss listening to same mail server will result in duplication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following spring-integration mail configuration. my version 1.0.4

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">


    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>

 <mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://user:pass@domain:993/inbox"                                    
                                  channel="recieveEmailChannel"
                                  auto-startup="true"                                      
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller> 
    <int:interval-trigger initial-delay="1000" interval="2000"
    fixed-rate="true"/>
    </int:poller>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">        
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>

<bean id="emailReceiverService" class="com.mycompany.DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService">
</bean>
```

**Question**

Two instances of Jboss server is running in different nodes and both are pointing to same mail server. I am doing some DB insertion in my DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService class. Is it possible for one mail dual entry in the db? In other words the same mail will be processed by both Jboss. If yes then how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: That is definitely a race condition. You must consider some form of transactioning of the email reading/processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, email is not a transactional resource. One technique is to ensure only one of the adapters is running at a time, using JMX, etc to start/stop the adapters as necessary - set auto-startup to "false" to prevent them starting during initialization and use management software to control them. An example of how to use another Spring Integration application to manage the adapters in another is shown in the 'monitoring' sample app (in the intermediate folder)...

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples

If you need multiple instances to handle the workload then you can distribute the work to other instances using AMQP, JMS etc.

If the second instance is simply for resiliency then your management app can monitor the two instances and if one goes down, start the adapter in the other.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I am looking into the samples, my SI version is 1.0.4 (not possible to upgrade) the quick think came to my mind is "does this work with 1.0.4?"

Comment: From this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-jmx) it looks like 1.0.4 is not available for spring-integration-jmx. So any other options I have?

Comment: Sorry - no - it would really benefit you greatly to take advantage of all the good work and move up to a current release.